# How to display the contents of URL1 when user visits URL2

Tags: page-template

I know how to do it with apache/mod_proxy, but I can't use mod_proxy on our shared host. So no .htaccess solutions.

Currently I have the following code in child theme's page.php

```
global $post ;
if( needs_replacement( $post ) ) {
  $post_name = $post->post_name ;
  $from_url = create_url( $post );
  $r = wp_remote_get( $from_url);
  echo wp_remote_retrieve_body( $r );
  exit(0);
}
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/page.php' );
?>
```

And it works. I am wondering what is the right way of doing this. $from_url is from the same server.

Example:

```
$post = https://example.com/docs/hello-world
$from_url = https://example.com/supp/?sec=hello-world
```

Making it clear, what I want to develop is a method that can get the *rendered page* content when I pass a URL. So something like:

```
function wp_get_url_content( $url ) {
  ....
}
```

The `$url` will always be a URL from the same server.

Comment: Do you mean the referrer? It's not 100% clear what you mean or why you're trying to do this, a little context as to the problem you're trying to solve would help us understand. Additionally, what do `needs_replacement` and `create_url` do and how do they work?

Comment: Basically I have a plugin that provides a short code. When added to a page that creates a menu structure and the URLs of the format `https://example.com/supp/?sec=hello-world` from URL `https://example.com/docs/hello-world`. the URL `https://example.com/docs/hello-world` is a wordpress page. If I open it it shows me the page contents but without the additional menus provided by `https://example.com/supp/?sec=hello-world`. So whenever a user goes to `https://example.com/docs/hello-world` I want  to show the content he gets when using `https://example.com/supp/?sec=hello-world`.

Answer (score 0):

Have WordPress (which creates the web server responses) respond with a redirect (via a call to `wp_redirect()`). Put as the first thing in `header.php`

```
global $post;
if( needs_replacement( $post ) ) {
  $from_url = create_url( $post );
  wp_redirect( $from_url );
  exit(0);
}
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/page.php' );
?>
```

(Note that you have to this first thing; otherwise, attempts to redirect will get ignored or more likely cause errors.)

Comment: An alternative (with greater distance from your approach) would be to use rewriting rather than redirecting. (Note: either can be done via WordPress rather than Apache.) In your case it might suffice to use `add_rewrite_endpoint()`

Comment: I know both solutions and actually using apache mod_rewrite currently for redirection. In these cases a 30x redirect is issued and the browser location shows the new URL that I want to avoid. I want to emulate something similar to redirect with mod_proxy.

Comment: In that case, you probably want a rewrite, not a redirect. Rewrite should cause WordPress internally to run as if the modified URL had been given initially, but the browser need never know. In contrast, redirect should cause the browser (or, in your case, the proxy) to re-request with the new URL, which would be the same as Apache (with mod_alias or mod_rewrite) redirection....

Comment: ...But I should double-check things -- there's a lot of confusion about (in the blogosphere ) because mod_rewrite can do both rewriting and redirecting. (Part of the confusion is that indeed you can emulate a rewrite via a proxy and a redirect.) A further point of possible confusion is that (though I should re-check my earlier work) it appears that WordPress mostly ignores attempts to rewrite via Apache, in favor of its own rewrite rules (for permalinks or via the calls alluded to earlier).

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule` did not help as it also changes the browser location. If I am wrong, can you post a simple example?

Comment: Yeah, looking at this more, it's hard to be certain when it's gonna do a redirect and when it's gonna do a redirect. But I thought of what's probably a better approach, using a WordPress hook. That's in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Thought of another approach)
Use a WordPress hook, and a call to `set_query_var()`.
Something like

```
function add_my_query_vars () {
   set_query_var('sec', 'hello world'); 
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','add_my_query_vars');
```

(This does make some likely assumptions about how the plugin handles query variables.)

Comment: Doesn't help much. I used `query_vars` hook to add sec as a valid query var and added the `sec` to the URL. Doesn't help because this works only with `/supp' URL, but what we actually have is '/docs' URL. Updating the question with my understanding, please check it.